# Multilingual Paragraphs fields are not present in node content

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

Following [these Instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/paragraphs/multilingual-paragraphs-configuration) I set up a paragraph field in custom node type. The field is called `field_content_sections` and it holds the paragraph elements. Next to it I created another field, the plain old list field called `field_content_rating_level`.

But when i create a node of that type with filled out parapgraph elements, the paragraph field doesn't appear in the nodes content, but the plain old list field does:

[image]

What I've done wrong?

I tried it with Drupal 8.5.6 and 8.6.0 and the most recent versions of the paragraphs module itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, that there was a conflict with the `field_layout` module. Just uninstalled it and voilá!